# How to sum the adjacent values around a given location in a 2D Array (Matrix)?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

```
int[][] array = new int[][]  { { 1, 2, 3 },
                               { 5, 6, 7 },
                               { 9, 0, 1 } 
                             };
```

Given this 2D Array and a location, Ex: `[0][2]` or 3, what kind of algorithm using for loops could I make to get the sum of the adjacent elements. It should be `3 + 2 + 6 + 7 = 18`. Boundaries do matter but I’m mostly interested in the summing portion.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hint: loop from row-1 to row+1 and there within from column-1 to column+1. Take care of minimum and maximum row and column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final int X_SIZE = 3;
private static final int Y_SIZE = 3;
private static int sumAdj(int x, int y, int[][] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = Math.max(x-1, 0); i <= Math.min(x+1, X_SIZE -1); i++) {
        for (int j = Math.max(y-1, 0); j <= Math.min(y+1, Y_SIZE-1); j++) {
            sum += array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Basically you want to loop the square whose center is the point you specify, this means min x is your center's x-1 and max x is your center's x+1, same for y. I am using Math.min and Math.max to take into consideration the boundaries, you can define your min and max coordinates outside the for loop using if statements but I find this way more elegant.

Comment: Nice and clean solution